# Displaying label text across multiple lines after reading from a CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, text, formatting, label

I am writing a program that reads questions from a CSV file for the user to answer. Once i read from the question CSV file, i store my questions in a list of Question objects. My GUI then displays each question to the user

```
Public Sub displayQuestion(ByVal x As Integer)
    QuizForm.questionLabel.Text = allQuestions(x).qText
 End Sub
```

and they are able to cycle through them via next/previous buttons. Each Question object has an associated string variable representing the question text.

Some questions are simple sentences such as

'Which of the following statements is the MOST valid goal for a test team?'

However, some questions are in the following format:

Which of the following statements are TRUE?

A. Software testing may be required to meet legal or contractual
requirements.

B. Software testing is mainly needed to improve the quality of the
developer’s work.

C. Rigorous testing and fixing of defects found can help reduce the risk of
problems occurring in an operational environment.

D. Rigorous testing is sometimes used to prove that all failures have been
found.

The trouble is, when reading a question text from the CSV file, it must be on one line. This then leads to questions structured like the second example above being displayed on my GUI like this:

[image]

Which isn't very user-friendly.

Id like it to be presented like this:

[image]

I understand how i would do this by hardcoding vbnewLine into the text, but the questions are all loaded dynamically at run-time.

Any suggestions to how i my go about this?

Comment: Labels for the question can be multi line.  The answer options could/should be checkboxes which can also be multi line.  Controls can also be anchored  or used with a layout panel,

Comment: I believe your problem is that you do not know how to structure the CSV (comma separated variable) file and parse its content for display.  Is this correct?  Think it through,  if each line if the file has multiple fields, you should be able to make decisions based on the information parsed from each line to decide how it should be displayed.   Also, consider using the [TextFieldParser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the file and extract the fields from each line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a vbNewLine at the end of your subroutine:

Public Sub displayQuestion(ByVal x As Integer)
    QuizForm.questionLabel.Text = allQuestions(x).qText & vbNewLine()
   End Sub

Don't make it harder on yourself then need be. Append a new line at the end of your Question String, nothing wrong with this.

Comment: This will just add a new line after the text for the question. The string containing the text for the question holds the whole question text. I'm looking for a way that when the program encounters a question which has structure like the 'Which of the following is true?' example above, the program is able to add vbNewLine() before the 'A:', 'B:', 'C' and 'D'